# Find whether a directory exists by specifying only its partial name

Tags: shell

I want to find whether a directory exists by just giving the partial name of the directory as the parameter. i.e if a directory by name /home/directory exists, i want to find if it exists by just giving /home/direc*

Is there any way to do this in shell script?

I tried the following but doesn't work:

```
directory=/home/direc*
if [[ -d "$directory" ]]; then
        echo found;
else
echo not found
fi
```

Comment: What if /home/direc* matches more than once, i.e. /home/directory and /home/director ? I assume you want to achieve something like tab completion in a script?

Comment: exactly.. basically i need to check whether a java folder with a specific version exists in /usr/lib/jvm.. many java versions exists but i need to find a specific one but i dont know its subversion so i cant give its full name..

Comment: Why are you using [[ -d "$directory" ]] instead of [ -d "$directory" ] ?

Comment: read somewhere that double brackets are faster

Answer (score 3):

```
directory=/home/direc*
for f in $directory
do
    if [ -d $f ]
    then
        echo $f
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "wc" to count the results and do it like this:

```
files=$(ls /home/dir* > /dev/null | wc -l)
if [ **"$files" != "0"** ]
then
echo "Dir exists"
else
echo "Doesn't exist"
fi
```